# RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 784]' is invalid for input of size 614400

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, runtime-error, transformer-model

I'm practicing code that implements the "Auto-Encoding Variable Bayes (VAE)" paper.
However, the error "RuntimeError:shape [16, 1, 28, 28] is invalid for input of size 37632" has not been resolved. I don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

```
EPOCHS = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 16
# Transformer code
transformer = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((28, 28)),
            transforms.ToTensor()
])

# Transform data
train_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root = "/home/seclab_dahae/dahye/VAE_data", transform = transformer)
train_set, test_set = train_test_split(train_set, test_size=0.2)
print("Train size is {}, test size is {} ".format(len(train_set), len(test_set)))

#test_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root = "/home/seclab_dahae/dahye/VAE_data", transform = transformer)

# Loading trainloader, testloader
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = True, num_workers = 2)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_set, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = True, num_workers = 2)
```

This is the code that brings my data to pytorch.

```
# VAE model
class VAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, image_size, hidden_size_1, hidden_size_2, latent_size): #28*28, 512, 256, 2
        super(VAE, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(image_size, hidden_size_1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size_1, hidden_size_2)
        self.fc31 = nn.Linear(hidden_size_2, latent_size)
        self.fc32 = nn.Linear(hidden_size_2, latent_size)

        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(latent_size, hidden_size_2)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(hidden_size_2, hidden_size_1)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(hidden_size_1, image_size)

    def encode(self, x):
        h1 = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        h2 = F.relu(self.fc2(h1))
        return self.fc31(h2), self.fc32(h2)

    def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
        std = torch.exp(0.5 * logvar)
        eps = torch.randn_like(std)
        return mu + std * eps

    def decode(self, z):
        h3 = F.relu(self.fc4(z))
        h4 = F.relu(self.fc5(h3))
        return torch.sigmoid(self.fc6(h4))

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(x.view(-1, 784))
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
        return self.decode(z), mu, logvar

VAE_model = VAE(28*28, 512, 256, 2).to(DEVICE)
optimizer = optim.Adam(VAE_model.parameters(), lr = 1e-3)
```

This is the part that implements the VAE model.

```
def loss_function(recon_x, x, mu, logvar):
    BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(recon_x, x.view(-1, 784), reduction = 'sum')
    KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())
    return BCE, KLD
```

Here is a code that implements a loss function.

```
def train(epoch, model, train_loader, optimizer):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = data.to(DEVICE)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        recon_batch, mu, logvar = model(data)

        BCE, KLD = loss_function(recon_batch, data, mu, logvar)

        loss = BCE + KLD

        loss.backward()

        train_loss += loss.item()

        optimizer.step()

        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\t Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader),
                loss.item() / len(data)))
            
    print("======> Epoch: {} Average loss: {:.4f}".format(
        epoch, train_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
    ))  

def test(epoch, model, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(test_loader):
            data = data.to(DEVICE)
            
            recon_batch, mu, logvar = model(data)
            BCE, KLD = loss_function(recon_batch, data, mu, logvar)

            loss = BCE + KLD
            test_loss += loss.item()

            if batch_idx == 0:
                n = min(data.size(0), 8)
                comparison = torch.cat([data[:n], recon_batch.view(BATCH_SIZE, 1, 28, 28)[:n]]) # (16, 1, 28, 28)
                grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(comparison.cpu()) # (3, 62, 242)
```

This is the train code and test code.
Jupiter's error occurred in the "recon_batch.view(BATCH_SIZE, 1, 28, 28)[:n]" section of the test code.

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(0, EPOCHS)):
    train(epoch, VAE_model, trainloader, optimizer)
    test(epoch, VAE_model, testloader)
    print("\n")
    latent_to_image(epoch, VAE_model)
```

Finally, This code is a trigger to start learning.
How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your test images are not 28 by 28 pixels. You are trying to [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#torch.reshape)/[`view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view) a tensor that is *not* 28 by 28 to a shape that is incompatible. Is it possible your test data is a batch of 600 images of size 32 by 32?

Note that when you [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#torch.reshape)/[`view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view) a tensor you only change the arrangement of elements, but you cannot change the number of elements in the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

A similar error was solved by replacing

```
mu, logvar = self.encode(x.view(-1, 784))
```

by

```
mu, logvar = self.encode(x.view(x.size(0), 784))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Shai's answer:

[16, 1, 28, 28] is invalid for input of size 37632

37632 is 16x3x1x28x28 ; possibly these images are RGB and not grayscale, which would add the extra x3 bytes